# Split Chinese Character problem using tocharArray()

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# program to split Chinese Character input like this

```
textbox input ="大大大"
expected output =
大
大
大
```

And the code is like this

```
string aa="大大大";
foreach (char c in aa.ToCharArray()){
     Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

It works fine for most of the characters.
However, for some characters such as "", I got the result like this

```
textbox input = 大
output =
口
口
大
```

It looks like that the program fail to handle this character

Is there any solution to solve this?

Comment: That looks like `\U2770f` which would be encoded as a surrogate pair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR:

- Don't use `ToCharArray()` when working with non-"ASCII" (or at least, non-Latin-style) text.
- Instead, [use `TextElementEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textelementenumerator?view=net-6.0).

  - [Here's why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/uax29-compliant-grapheme-enumeration).

### Explanation

In Unicode, [the  character](https://unicode-table.com/en/2770F/) has a code-point of `U+2770F` which is outside the range supported by a single 16-bit UTF-16 value (i.e. 2 bytes, a single .NET `Char` value), so UTF-16 uses [a pair of separate 16-bit values known as a *surrogate pair* to represent it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/surrogate-pairs):

```
using Shouldly;

String input = "";
Char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
chars.Length.ShouldBe( 2 ); // 2*Char == 2*16-bits == 32 bits

Char.GetUnicodeCategory( chars[0] ).ShouldBe( UnicodeCategory.Surrogate );
Char.GetUnicodeCategory( chars[1] ).ShouldBe( UnicodeCategory.Surrogate );
```

Therefore, to meaingfully "split" a string like this, your program needs to be aware of surrogate-pairs and *not* split a pair up.

The code below is a simple program that extracts each Unicode code-point from a string and adds it to a list.

```
String input = "大大";

// Don't forget to Normalize!
input = input.Normalize();

List<UInt32> codepoints = new List<UInt32>( capacity: 3 );

for( Int32 i = 0; i < input.Length; i++ )
{
    Char c = input[i];

    if( Char.GetUnicodeCategory( c ) == UnicodeCategory.Surrogate )
    {
        Char former = c;
        Char latter = input[i+1];
   
        // The former sibling has the upper 11 bits of the code-point (after 0x00D800).
        // The latter sibling has the lower 10 bits of the code-point.

        UInt32 hi = former;
        UInt32 lo = latter;

        UInt32 codepoint = ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (lo - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;

        codepoints.Add( codepoint  );

        i += 1; // Skip the next char
    }
    else
    {
        codepoints.Add( c );
    }
} 

codepoint.Dump();
// [0] =  22823 == '大'
// [1] = 161551 == ''
// [2] =  22823 == '大'
```

Note that when it comes to non-Latin-style alphabets, the concept of splitting a string up into discrete characters, glyphs, or graphemes is... complicated. But in general, you **don't** want to split a string up into discrete `Char` values (Q.E.D.), but also you shouldn't split a string up into code-points either, instead you'll want to split a string up into **grapheme clusters** (a visual-grouping of related glyphs, each represented by their own codepoints, which in-turn may be a single .NET 16-bit `Char` value, or a Surrogate Pair of `Char` values).

Fortunately .NET has this functionality built-in into `System.Globalization.TextElementEnumerator`.

```
using System.Globalization;

String input = "大大".Normalize();

TextElementEnumerator iter = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator( input );
while( iter.MoveNext() )
{
    String graphemeCluster = iter.GetTextElement();
    Console.WriteLine( graphemeCluster );
}
```

Gives me the expected output:

```
大

大
```

Comment: thanks, my problem solved by using your suggestion using StringInfo